# Why does this compile if the class is incomplete type?

Tags: c++, incomplete-type, template-instantiation

In Memory.h I have:

```
#pragma once

class Memory
{public:
    template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
    static T* newAlloc(TArgs ... args)
    {
        return new T(args ...);
    }
};
```

And in main.cpp I have:

```
#include "Memory.h" // The template class is defined here

class Foo
{public:
    Foo(int a, const char* c) {}
};

int main()
{
    Memory::newAlloc<Foo>(7, "str");

}
```

And this compiles fine even though Foo isn't fully defined until after I pasted in Memory.h. I'm confused about why this compiles. Isn't it true the equivalent code after the compiler has pasted in Memory.h is like this in main.cpp:

```
class Memory
{
public:
    static Foo* newAlloc(int a, const char* c)
    {
        return new Foo(a, c);
    }
};

class Foo
{public:
    Foo(int a, const char* c) {}
};

int main()
{
      Memory::newAlloc(7, "str");
}
```

??? Because this doesn't compile, I get the error:

> 'newAlloc' identifier not found 'newAlloc' is not a member of
> Memory

Basically it wants the full definition of Foo. If I place the Foo class definition above the Memory one it then compiles fine. So given that my second version is the equivalent of code after template instantiation (is it?) then why does the first version compile but the second not?

I am on Visual Studio 2019 16.4.5

Comment: `#include` is a simple copy-paste, but tempate instantiation is not so simple mechanism. There's no requirement to actually put that generated code anywhere, it's enough that compiler knows what it is supposed to do.

Comment: `Memory::newAlloc<Foo>` is instantiated in `main` where definition of `Foo` is complete.

Comment: You can do some [weird and wonderful things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) with templates.

Comment: You are asking about the famous "Two phase lookup".

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it true the equivalent code after the compiler has pasted in Memory.h is like this in main.cpp:

No, it isn't true. This would be equivalent:

```
class Memory
{public:
    template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
    static T* newAlloc(TArgs ... args)
    {
        return new T(args ...);
    }
};


class Foo
{public:
    Foo(int a, const char* c) {}
};

int main()
{
    Memory::newAlloc<Foo>(7, "str");

}
```

You'll find that this compiles.

> why does the first version compile

It works because `Foo` is defined before the template is instantiated with `Foo` as template argument.

Answer (score 1):

> this compiles fine even though Foo isn't fully defined until after I pasted in Memory.h

Yes, because by the time `Memory::newAlloc` is instantiated here:

```
Memory::newAlloc(7, "str");
```

the definition of `Foo` already exists, and so this compiles fine.

---

> Isn't it true the equivalent code after the compiler has pasted in Memory.h is like this in main.cpp:

No, in this case, on this line:

```
static Foo* newAlloc(int a, const char* c)
```

since `Foo` has not yet been defined, the code will not compile.